# Can I Join Two Array - PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I want to combine the two arrays, which have the same structure.

This my first array :

```
[rows] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [kdregister] => 10865701
        [pagu] => 339.4157454
        [real] => 328.633577646
        [real2] => 328.633577646
        )
)
```

This is the second array :

```
[row] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [kdregister] => 10865701
        [kegiatan] => name the game
        [pagu] => 0
        [real] => 0
        [real2] => 0
        )
)
```

and i have same value

```php
    [kdregister] => 10865701
```

and I want to have results like this

```
[row] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [kdregister] => 10865701
        [kegiatan] => name the game
        [pagu] => 0
        [real] => 0
        [real2] => 0
        [pagu] => 339.4157454
        [real] => 328.633577646
        [real2] => 328.633577646
        )
```

Can you help me guys? Thanks!!

Comment: Your required result is unfortunately an INVALID Array, you cannot have 2 occurances with the same key

Comment: but if in one of the arrays I try to replace the key, can you help me? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Rafy, you can do like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0261faddbdad4b18d2f63bf7aeac96359c68901), you must have different keys for solving your problem.

Comment: and one problem again, in this array have many data

Comment: @Rafy, if you wanna merge your arrays by `kdregister` you need to separate `keys` which you wanna present in resultant array.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this man, this work for me !

```
        $array_merge = array_merge($array1,$array2);
        $array = array();

        foreach ($array_merge['row'] as $key1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($array_merge['rows'] as $key2 => $value2) {
                if ($value1['kdregister'] == $value2['kdregister']) {
                    $array[$key2] = array_merge($value1,$value2);
                }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be `array_merge_recursive()` but this will not create the array you wanted as that would be impossible. It would create a usable array containing 2 occurances of the data in the `rows` array

```
// setup your example arrays
$a1['rows'][] = ['kdregister' => 10865701, 'pagu' => 339.4157454, 'real' => 328.633577646, 'real2' => 328.633577646];
$a2['rows'][] = ['kdregister' => 10865701, 'kegiatan'=> 'Name of game', 'pagu' => 0, 'real' => 0, 'real2' => 0];

$a3 = array_merge_recursive($a1,$a2);
print_r($a3);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kdregister] => 10865701
                    [pagu] => 339.4157454
                    [real] => 328.633577646
                    [real2] => 328.633577646
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [kdregister] => 10865701
                    [kegiatan] => Name of game
                    [pagu] => 0
                    [real] => 0
                    [real2] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge two arrays, you need to use array_merge method and to filter out unique characters you need to do something like this:

```
$ab = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
```

Comment: This actually would loose some of the data!

Comment: it's impossible to have the same indexes in a single array.

Comment: Yes so if they actually want all the data as you have to assume they do from their requested result array, this will not do that

Comment: in that case you need to build an array which should have unique indexes, values of indexes will be as it is but you need to change the indexes/key of the resultant array,

Comment: I know, see my answer